# Kernels 4.15.0-29 through -36 caused top panel network options to disappear. 18.04 16.xx

Tags: kernel, 18.04

I did a Software Update today. I probably shouldn't have.

Like the last kernel 4.15.0-24 that broke a bunch of stuff, and was finally withdrawn, this update installed kernel 4.15.0-29, and now my wired/wireless network icons and menus in the top panel are now gone or messed up.

My wired connection still auto-connects, but doesn't display a network icon in the top panel, and not all of my network scripts show in the menu. Restarting network-manager brings back the top panel network icon, but doesn't fix the menus.

None of the wireless network menu items appear at all. The only way to connect to a wireless network is through the settings panel.

Booting back to the -24 kernel doesn't put things back as they were before.

Any ideas on what's wrong with the -29 kernel/update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The problem was that there were dkms drivers that were tainting the -29 kernel.</strike>

You can see if you have a tainted kernel with:

```
grep -i taint /var/log/syslog*
```

Then I did a **dkms remove** of the broadcom and r8168 dkms drivers.

And I uninstalled:

- broadcom-sta-dkms
- r8168-dkms

rebooted, and the top panel icon/menu were back to normal.

**Update #1:**

Well, I spoke too soon. The problem is back. The ethernet interface is screwy. I booted into Windows 10, once, and the ethernet interface worked fine. I'll have to test some more, but it looks like a Ubuntu problem... one that only showed up after the -29 kernel update.

**Update #2:**

<strike>Lets try this again. I removed the GNOME shell extension **GSConnect** [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/), and then manually deleted the bits and pieces of software that it left behind, and then manually uninstalled **kdeconnect**. My network icon is back in the top panel, and the network menus now correctly show the ethernet and wireless interfaces... and funny enough, it also fixed a problem with **Software & Updates** where it wouldn't allow me to select/deselect repositories!</strike>

**Update #3:**

Well, everything in Update #2 didn't really fix the problem(s). I note that if I boot the machine with the wireless connected, and the ethernet unplugged, it all works fine. If I then connect the ethernet cable, it never connects, and it looks like I never obtain an IPv4 network address. I *think* that if I boot with the ethernet cable already connected, the original symptoms with the icon/menu are there. I don't believe that netplan has anyting to do with the problem. I also note, in case example of one, that if I boot Windows 10, then Ubuntu 18.04, it all seems to work as expected.

**Update #4:**

<strike>If you're running on a SSD, you run the risk of things  booting faster than the network is coming online and then you'll need to modify the following file: `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service`</strike>

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager Wait Online
Documentation=man:nm-online(1)
Requires=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
Before=network-online.target
```

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=**60**
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target

and change the timeout from `30` to `60`.

**Update #5:**

Darn. Update #4 really didn't fix the problem after all.

**Update #6:**

**The network problems in 18.04 (and probably updated 16.xx too) occurred in kernels 4.15.0-29 through -36. Upgrading to 18.10 with its 4.18 kernel, fixes the problem! Yeah!**

Comment: This answer clearly shows that the original question is not off topic because of a bug as some reviewers thought, so if it is closed as off topic anyway it will have to be reopened because there is a software fix for it.

Comment: @karel well, new update... I do still have a problem. I'm confused. I've never had ethernet  problems until the -29 update came out. I don't think it's a netplan problem, even though no information was given about any changeover to netplan in 18.04.x. All of the NetworkManager files seem in order.